# Python3 Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, python-3.x, screen-scraping

> urllib.error.URLError urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

I got this error by when try to fetch notino.com . I guess the guy used some clever way to prevent the screen **scraper** . I tried to add header and cookie but this doesn't work

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://www.notino.com"
html = urlopen(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An auto-bot detection mechanism is most likely dropping your connection. You should provide a `User-Agent` header to fake a browser visit - worked for me:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'})
>>> response.status_code
200
```

Using [`requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) in this example.

Comment: Still got the same error using your code


import requests
url = "https://www.notino.com"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'})
response.status_code

Comment: @NhanHuynh that might mean that your IP is in the black list already, just a theory..

Comment: Ok, It did work on my Amazon Cloud but not on my computer which IP address is in VIetNam